# Как добавить string-array в ArrayList<String>, если CheckBox активен

Tags: android, строки, checkbox

Из первой "активности" я передал статус CheckBox, один checkbox - один string-array

```
<string-array name="number">
        <item>one</item>
        <item>two</item>
        <item>three</item>
        <item>four</item>
        <item>five</item>
    </string-array>
```

Что нужно писать, там где знак "?" или в другом месте, чтобы добавить string-array в ArrayList, чтоб в последующем рандомное слово вывести в TextView

```
if (check1){
            number.add(?);
        }
```

Код второй "активности"

```
ArrayList<String> number = new ArrayList<>();
        Boolean check1 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("grade1");
        Boolean check2 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("grade2");
        Boolean check3 = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("grade3");

        if (check1){
            number.add(?);
        }
        if (check2){
            number.add(?);
        }
        if (check3){
            number.add(?);
        }
        TextView view_number = findViewById(R.id.view_number);
        Button go_new = findViewById(R.id.new_number);
        go_new.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random r = new Random();
                int randomitem = r.nextInt(number.size());
                String randomElement = number.get(randomitem);
                view_number.setText(randomElement);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так получаем string-array из ресурсов:

```
String[] arrayNumber = resources.getStringArray(R.array.number);
```

Так добавляем все элемкнты этого массива в коллекцию ArrayList:

```
number.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayNumber));
```

Comment: Нет метода `addAll`, принимающего массив - только коллекции, исправьте на: `number.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayNumber));`

Comment: ну да, это же не котлин